# my own design vs asp.net forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

i have been using asp.net's forms authentication to restrict users when they try to access the web pages. As you know, in forms authentication, you need to edit web.config file in order to give rights to users accessing web pages. 
Now i want to change this design. i dont want to apply asp.net's logic. i want to store the information which user roles can access to which pages on my database with my own designed tables. 
i want to know if there are some extra integrated security protection of asp.net's forms authentication. if so, then i should apply these security consepts too. But if forms authentication is only for simplfying the logic about authentication, then my own design will be enough. 
Any opinion?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing authorization with authentication - authentication is validating that the user is who they say they are, and authorization is what they can do.

So you are probably looking to implement a custom Membership provider - you don't have to store the roles information in web.config.  You can continue to use forms authentication for the login part.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

Comment: why shouldnt i just use my own design about membership insead of using custom membership also. it provides more simplicity but i dont need it. does it also come with security protections? if so then i should think about custom membership. if not, my own design and controls(login, roles, accessing pages) will be enough. By the way i just copied and pasted the word authentication because it is hard to spell:) so i copied the wrong word. thanks

Comment: Simply, because you'll make mistakes, and the tiniest error will invalidate the whole thing.